# Prove that $(a-b)^n\mid (a^n-b^n) \iff n=1$ under given conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

Suppose that $a,b,(a-b)$ are pairwise co-prime (i.e. $a\perp b\perp (a-b)\perp a$), and that $\frac{a}{2}<b<a$, where $a$ and $b$ are both positive integers greater than $2$.  Let $n$ be odd.  Prove or disprove that $(a-b)^n\mid (a^n-b^n)$ iff $n=1$.

I can see that one possible implication is that
$$a\equiv b   \pmod{(a-b)^n},$$
from which $(a-b)^n\mid (a-b)$ which is true iff $n=1$.

But is this the **only** implication?

Note $a\perp b$ means that $\rm{gcd}(a,b)=1$.

Comment: What does $a\perp b$ mean?

Comment: @WillJagy Can you answer this?

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstanding - by $\gcd(a,b,(a-b))=1$ you mean that their pairwise gcd'es are 1 or the common of all three numbers is 1?

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka Yes, they are pairwise co-prime

Comment: If $a \not\perp b\not\perp (a-b)$, then $n$ is not unique.  For example $10^3-5^3=(10-5)(10-5)(2^2\cdot 5+2\cdot 5 +5)$ so that $(10-5)^3\mid 10^3-5^3$.

Comment: Why is it the hardest?

Comment: I'd suggest you change the title, it's obnoxious.

Comment: Give me an answer first.  Then I'll change it.  Not trying to be obnoxious.  It's the hardest because no-one can answer it yet.

Comment: @ElementaryNut Dude, there are way harder problems on MSE.

Comment: There are questions that haven't been answered far longer. The title has now been edited, don't edit it back.

Comment: Your conclusion that $a = b \mod (a-b)^n$ is incorrect. You took an $n$th root but those have multiple solutions mod $m$ in general.

Comment: @nayrb  I think you've made a serious mistake.  It's obvious that $n=1$ is a possible specific solution - not to  be confused with a general solution.

Comment: @nayrb You should have realized that an implication is not the same as an iff statement.

Comment: Note: $a^n = (b + (a-b))^n = b^n + \sum_{k = 1}^n \binom{n}{k}b^{n-k}(a-b)^k$. Hence $a^n - b^n \equiv ?? \pmod{(a-b)^2}$?

Comment: @ElementaryNut: Please keep the title of your question about the problem; clickbait-like statements do not help in any way and can be perceived as annoying or even obnoxious.

Comment: @DanielFischer has sketched the first steps for n=2 being a solution.  But the question asks for odd n.

Answer (score 3):

I guess OP missed the obvious counterexample $a-b=1$. So, I will assume $a-b\ge 2$, in particular, it has a prime divisor.

The case $n=1$ is obvious. Suppose $n\ge3$. Let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $a-b$, and let $v_p(m)$ denote the power of $p$ in $m$. Then, by [Lifting the Exponent lemma](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwispe_ggYjNAhVW3GMKHRbGC8IQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.artofproblemsolving.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fid%3DYXR0YWNobWVudHMvNC81LzYyZTQ0NjJlOGZhYzkwMmQwNzAxOTgyOTViMjY1Y2I2NGRhNjcx%26rn%3DTGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm&usg=AFQjCNGhUS19IaLGtIp6AL_eb0T7IBl7Sg&sig2=ngvQzZemBdHk51yBphsSIg)
$$v_p(a^n-b^n)=v_p(a-b)+v_p(n)$$
However, $(a-b)^n|a^n-b^n$ implies
$$n\cdot v_p(a-b)\le v_p(a^n-b^n)=v_p(a-b)+v_p(n)$$
So, we have
$$(n-1)v_p(a-b)\le v_p(n)\implies p^{n-1}\le p^{(n-1)v_p(a-b)}\le p^{v_p(n)}\le n$$
However, $p\ge 3,n\ge 3$ gives contradiction. So, $a-b$ has no prime odd prime divisor. So, $a-b=2^m$ for some $m$.

As expected, we will continue with LTE's special case for $p=2$. Let $k=v_2(n)$, then, in particular, $2^k\le n$. If $m\ge 2$, then, $4|a-b$, so,
$$v_2(a^n-b^n)=v_2(a-b)+v_2(n)=m+k$$
Moreover, $(a-b)^n|a^n-b^n$ gives
$$mn=n\cdot v_2(a-b)\le v_2(a^n-b^n)=m+k\implies 2(n-1)\le m(n-1)\le k$$
$$\implies 4^{n-1}\le 2^k\le n$$
As $n\ge 3$, we still have contradiction.
The last case is $a-b=2$, then, $a,b$ are both odd, so, they have different residues modulo $4$. As $n$ is odd,
$$a^n\equiv a\not\equiv b\equiv b^n\pmod4$$
So, $4\nmid a^n-b^n$. Thus, $(a-b)^n=2^n\nmid a^n-b^n$.